# Removing Script Tags and Reloading Them keeps reloading the scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script with desired behavior of the following steps:

1. Loop through src attributes of script tags - working
2. Check the src values with a switch case statement and add them to arrays - working
3. Use $("script").remove()  function call to remove all script tags - working
4. **Add scripts reordered in arrays to the bottom of the html body **<-----problem area**
   It adds the scripts but it keeps loading them and reloading them**

I have been testing/debugging using firefox/firebug. Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Below is the  Javascript/Code where I believe the problem is arising:

```
//loop through the script tags
$("script").each(function (i) { //begin each function
    switch ($(this).attr("src")) { //begin switch case 
        case undefined:
            //store the script tag in the embeddedJS array
            embeddedJS.push($("script")[i].outerHTML);
            break;
        case "assets/js/jquery.js":
            jQuery.push($("script")[i].outerHTML);
            break;
        case "assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js":
            jQuery.push($("script")[i].outerHTML);
            break;
        case "assets/js/thememaker-gui.js":
            jQuery.push($("script")[i].outerHTML);
            break;
        default:
            //store the script tag in the embeddedJS array
            embeddedJS.push($("script")[i].outerHTML);
            break;
    } //end switch case
}); //end each function
//debug only
console.log("\n" + jQuery.join("\n") + embeddedJS.join("\n"));
//remove script tags
$("script").remove();
//append the jsDependencies right before the closing </body>tag
$("\n" + jQuery.join("\n") + embeddedJS.join("\n")).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: is this code inside one of the script files that gets readded?

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake. I appreciate your help. It must be looping over and over again because it is loading a script that contains the code.